# getenv("APPDATA") returns incorrect values if current user having username containing unicode characters

Tags: c, winapi, platform, windows-api-code-pack, getenv

Windows gives an api to get environment variable values using getenv(). If current user is having username containing localised characters (i.e. multibyte characters), then getenv returns incorrect value.

current user with username: `テスト` :
`getenv("AppData")` returns `C:\Users\???\AppData\Roaming`

It should return `C:\Users\テスト\AppData\Roaming`

Is there any alternative to `getenv` in Windows?

Comment: Maybe try the wide string version: [_wgetenv_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-s-wgetenv-s?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Windows doesn't use multibyte characters, you'll have to get your program's locale correct to get the proper conversion.  Type chcp at the command prompt and tell us what you see.

Comment: While “APPDATA” is doubtless a windows environment variable I like the platform agnosticism inherent in using ‘getenv’. This is ruined by using either the windows API or MS C extensions. The proper solution should be to setup the crt to use a utf8 encoding. I recall some dev on Twitter mentioning that UTF-8 was going to be a supported ACP in a windows 10 update but I never saw anything more official so I doubt this option is practically possible yet.

Comment: Ah. It’s the April 2018 Update that allowed UTF8 to be set as the system default locale and presumably c-runtime apps would inherit that. That’s a bit annoying as it’s tricky to convince users that changing system settings that may detrimentally effect other apps to support your app is a good idea. Would have been nice if utf8 as a default locale could be enabled via the app manifest or something. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `getenv` is not a Windows API function. That function is provided by the C runtime. If you wish to continue with a C runtime function, then rather than using `getenv`, you should use the Unicode version, [`_wgetenv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-wgetenv?view=vs-2019).

The Windows API function, which `getenv` and `_wgetenv` wrap, is [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getenvironmentvariable). You could equally use that function, but you must make sure that you target Unicode when building, or call the Unicode version `GetEnvironmentVariableW` explicitly.

That answers the direct question that you asked. However, it is also worth pointing out that reading the `APPDATA` variable is not the correct way to obtain that information. You should instead call [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) passing `FOLDERID_RoamingAppData`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any alternative to getenv in windows?

The most accurate way to get a user's `APPDATA` folder is to ask the OS directly, not query the environment of the calling process at all.

You can use [`SHGetFolderPathW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw) with `CSIDL_(LOCAL_)APPDATA`.

On Vista and later, you can (and should) alternatively use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) with `FOLDERID_(Roaming|Local)AppData`.